# Unsere liebe Frau

Tags: word-usage

Vor kurzem sah ich (seit langem wieder einmal) eine Werbeanzeige für einen Wein mit dem schönen Namen "Liebfraumilch" bzw. "Liebfrauenmilch". Zitat aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebfrauenmilch): *Ihren Ursprung hat die Liebfrauenmilch in den Weinbergen der Liebfrauenkirche in Worms (Rheinhessen).*

"Liebe Frau" bzw. "[Unsere liebe Frau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsere_Liebe_Frau)" ist eine alte Bezeichnung für Maria, die Mutter Jesu. Ähnliche Bezeichnungen gibt es in vielen Sprachen:

- Englisch: Our Lady
- Französisch: Notre Dame
- Spanisch: Nuestra Señora
- Portugiesisch: Nossa Senhora
- Italienisch: Nostra Signora

Deutsch scheint hier ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal zu haben - es heißt nicht "Unsere Frau", sondern "Unsere *liebe* Frau".

Meine Frage: Gibt es eine Erklärung für die Ergänzung des Attributs "liebe" im Deutschen? Falls die Frage eher in einen anderen Zweig von *stackexchange* gehört, kann ich sie gerne aus *german.stackexchange* löschen.

PS. In manchen Kirchennamen wird das "lieb" (zumindest umgangsprachlich) weggelassen:

- Frauenkirche in Dresden (ursprünglich Kirche Unserer Lieben Frau)
- Frauenkirche in München (offiziell Dom zu Unserer Lieben Frau)

Sicher lassen sich weitere Beispiele finden.

Übrigens wird auch im Niederländischen "Onze Lieve Vrouw" gesagt.

Comment: Vielleicht passt die Frage auch ins [Christianity SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Vgl. auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsere_Liebe_Frau.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich bin weder historisch noch theologisch bewandert genug, um hier fundiert Auskunft geben zu können. Aber beim Suchen im DWB bin ich auf folgende Passage gestoßen, die zum Thema paßt.

Luther spricht im *Sendbrief vom Dolmetschen* ([zeno.org](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Traktate/Ein+Sendbrief+vom+Dolmetschen)) über die richtige Übersetzung von Lukas 1, 28.

> Item da der Engel Mariam grüsset und spricht: Gegrüsset seistu, Maria vol gnaden, der Herr mit dir? Wolan, so ists biß her, schlecht den lateinischen buchstaben nach verdeutschet, sage mir aber ob solchs auch gut deutsch sey? Wo redet der deutsch man also: du bist vol gnaden? Und welcher Deutscher verstehet, was gsagt sey, vol gnaden? Er mus dencken an ein vas vol bier, oder beutel vol geldes, darumb hab ichs vordeutscht: Du holdselige, da mit doch ein Deutscher, dester meher hin zu kan dencken, was der engel meinet mit seinem grus. Aber hie wöllen die Papisten toll werden uber mich, das ich den Engelischen grus verderbet habe. Wie wol ich dennoch da mit nicht das beste deutsch habe troffen. **Und hette ich das beste deutsch hie sollen nemen, und den grus also verdeutschen: Gott grusse dich, du liebe Maria (denn so vil wil der Engel sagen, und so wurde er geredt haben, wan er hette wollen sie deutsch grussen),** ich halt, sie solten sich wol selbs erhenckt haben fur grosser andacht, zu der lieben Maria, das ich den grus so zu nichte gemacht hette.

> Aber was frage ich darnach? sie toben oder rasen, jch wil nicht wehren, das sie verdeutschen was sie wöllen, ich wil aber auch verdeutschen, nicht wie sie wöllen, sonder wie ich wil, wer es nicht haben wil, der las mirs stehen, und halt seine meisterschafft bey sich, denn ich wil ir weder sehen noch hören, sie dorffen fur mein dolmetzschen nicht antwort geben, noch rechenschafft thun, Das hörestu wol, ich wil sagen: du holdselige Maria, du liebe Maria, und las sie sagen: du volgnaden Maria. **Wer Deutsch kan, der weis wol, welch ein hertzlich fein wort das ist: die liebe Maria, der lieb Gott, der liebe Keiser, der liebe fürst, der lieb man, das liebe kind. Und ich weis nicht, ob man das wort ›liebe‹ auch so hertzlich und gnugsam in Lateinischer oder andern sprachen reden müg, das also dringe und klinge ynns hertz, durch alle sinne, wie es thut in unser sprache.**

Ich weiß nicht, ob der Gebrauch von *lieb* in Bezug auf Maria hier seinen Ursprung genommen hat. Jedenfalls behauptet Luther, daß das deutsche Wort im Vergleich zu anderen Sprachen einen besonderen Klang habe.

Answer (score 4):

Die Wortverbindung *Unsere liebe Frau* stammt wohl aus dem Mittelalter. Dafür spricht nicht nur, dass der Text [*Unser lieben Frauen Traum*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unser_lieben_Frauen_Traum) vor 1600 entstanden ist, sondern auch die alte Genitiv-Form in *Unser lieben Frauen*. Damit ist *Frau* hier wohl eine Entsprechung des mittelhochdeutschen [*frouwe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frouwe), ein Begriff, der im Weiblichkeitskonzept des Mittelalters als Gegensatz zum *wîp* zu verstehen ist, und die Dame des höheren Standes bezeichnet. *Frau* heißt hier also eher soviel wie "Dame, Herrin". Das entspricht auch den von dir zitierten Entsprechungen in den anderen Sprachen.

Ich bin leider in der Minnelyrik überhaupt nicht bewandert. Aber da die Hypothese hier noch fehlt, will ich sie zumindest erwähnen. Jemand, der sich in der Materie auskennt, möge mich verbessern. Ich vermute, dass die Wortverbindung *unsere liebe Frau* ihren Ursprung in der Minnelyrik hat.

Nur ein passendes Beispiel ist ein Minnelied des Ulrich von Liechtenstein von 1257: [*Der frouwe pouch*](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/germanica/Chronologie/13Jh/Liechtenstein/lie_frau.html).
Ich zitiere die ersten beiden Strophen:

> Got müeze wîbes êren phlegen,
> daz ist mîn stæter morgensegen.
> got müez ir sêl und lîp bewarn,
> got lâz si nimmer missevarn.
>
> Ez wil diu liebe frouwe mîn
> daz ich ir tiht ditz püechelîn.
> daz tuon ich gern, und swaz si wil,
> es sî lützel oder vil.
> si ist mir liep für elliu wîp

Ich übersetze das in etwa wie folgt (Die Mittelhochdeutsch-Vorlesung ist schon eine Weile her, die Übersetzung ist also mit einem Körnchen Salz zu nehmen. Es kommt mir hier nur auf die Opposition der Begriffe *frouwe* und *wîp* an):

> Gott möge die Ehre der Frau schützen
> Das ist mein täglicher Morgensegen
> Gott schütze ihre Seele und und ihren Leib
> Gott lasse ihr kein Unglück geschehen
>
> Meine liebe Frau (*frouwe*) will
> Dass ich ihr dieses Büchlein dichte
> Das tu ich gern, und was immer sie will,
> Sei es wenig oder viel
> Sie ist mir lieb vor allen Frauen (*wîp*)

Hier steht die *liebe frouwe* als die erwählte, geliebte Frau, im Gegensatz zu dem Rest der Frauen, die hier als *wîp* angesprochen werden.

Ich kann mir gut vorstellen, dass die Vorstellung der hochgestellten, angebeteten Frau, im christlichen Bereich auf die Gottesmutter Maria angewandt worden ist.

Es ist aber, wie gesagt, nur eine spekulative Hypothese.

Comment: Egal, ob spekulativ oder nicht - ein sehr interessanter Beitrag! Außerdem wurde mir bewusst, dass "Frau" nicht einfach "Person weiblichen Geschlechts" bedeutet, sondern aufgrund der mittelhochdeutschen Herkunft eher mit [Herrin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frouwe) gleichgesetzt werden sollte. Das passt auch besser zu "Lady", "Dame", "Señora" etc.