# Why is it Liebfrauenkirche, not LiebfrauKirche?

Tags: compound, word-formation

I guess *Liebfrau* means mother Mary. So I thought St. Mary church can be called *Liebfraukirche* or *Liebfrauekirche* (because Kirche is female noun). But why is it *Liebfrauenkirche*? I think I've seen many such cases.

Comment: I don't think your initial assumption holds. St Mary Church simply would be Marienkirche

Comment: @planetmaker Look at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsere_Liebe_Frau.

Comment: See also [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/62260/34192) question.

Comment: Both variants "Liebfraukirche" and "Liebfrauenkirche" occur.  Just make a Google search for these two words. In my opinion the second variant sounds better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for building compound nouns are very complicated, and there are more exceptions than rules. But the rule for building compound nouns with "Frau" is easy: Always use "Frauen":

> Frauenbund, Frauenheld, Frauenhandel, Frauenteam, Frauenkleid, Frauenwelt, Frauenwahlrecht, Frauenarzt, Frauensauna, Frauenschuh, Frauenmangel, Frauenzimmer, Frauenstreik, Frauenjournal, Frauenmörder, Frauenstimme, Frauenhut, Frauenheilkunde, Frauengürtel, Frauenkirche, Frauenkörper, Frauenname, Frauenrecht, Frauenbild, Frauenanteil, Frauenchor, Frauenhaus, Frauenpartei, Frauenmode, Frauenparkplatz, Frauenabend, ...

Although it looks like a plural it isn't. It is just the form you use for compound words. You can read more about this topic in the wikipedia articles about [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) and [Komposition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)) (both in German).

Comment: thanks, is it commont for 'weak nouns'?

Comment: As I said: there are more exceptions than rules. But it's true: most weak nouns have this -en- in compositions, but not all: Stirn (forehead), Erbe (heritage) and Uhr (clock) are a weak nouns, but "Stirnenlampe", "Erbentante" and "Uhrenwerk" are wrong, "Stirnlampe", "Erbtante" and "Uhrwerk" are correct. Also all words ending in -heit or -keit are weak, but they go with -s- in compositions: "Krankheitsbild, Tätigkeitsbereich"

Comment: That said, there **are** nouns with _Erben-_ (Erbenaufruf, Erbenversammlung) and of course _Erbs-_ (Erbseinsetzung) as well. More exceptions than rules? Frankly, I find it hard to discern any rules here.

Comment: I cannot help but think this answer does not quite resolve a possible misunderstanding by the OP. The remark "because Kirche is female noun" from the question suggests that the OP might somehow be trying to apply adjective endings to "Liebfrau" here.